# The word 'hub' as an effective center

Tags: meaning, word-usage

It seems that the word 'hub' is beginning to gain popularity as 'an effective center'. My questions is, when do people start using it in this sense?

Comment: Do you mean when did people start using it? It's been around for decades.

Comment: hub is used when there is a hub-and-spoke system in transportation or for airports or similar systems. Some cities have hub airports from where flights branch out like spokes to other cities. This originally comes from wooden wagon wheels.

Comment: @Michael: lam asking about using it in the sense of 'a center', such as 'world coffee hub'.

Comment: If there is a hub, spokes are always implied. a world coffee hub means people come there from all over, like to the center of a wheel (hub) to buy coffee. Hub is a common descriptive term used in international trade.

Comment: When was the wheel invented?

Comment: Well,it came after the chicken or the egg.

Answer (score 2):

The first metaphoric use of [*hub*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hub#etymonline_v_14521) to mean a center of activity or interest occurs in an essay by Oliver Wendell Holmes collected into *The Autocrat of the Breakfast-Table* in 1858:

> Boston State-House is the [*hub*](https://archive.org/details/autocratofbreakf00holm/page/120) of the solar system. You couldn’t pry that out of a Boston man, if you had the tire of all creation straightened out for a crowbar. — p. 120.

Shortened to The Hub and robbed of most of its irony, it became a [nickname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_nicknames) for Boston still used today.

From there, it was used in a more general sense for other cities:

> Having for its starting point the central city [St. Louis],the destined commercial [*hub*](https://books.google.de/books?id=8nsuAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22commercial+hub%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH-qCOvoLhAhWJYVAKHYN3BJU4FBDoATAHegQIARAf) of the continent taking its course to the sea, and spreading its many branches as it advances, until it taps every commercial artery of the South… — L. U. Reavis, *Saint Louis, the Commercial Metropolis of the Mississippi Valley*, 1874.

In the late 1880s, the somewhat more literal notion of a railway hub arose:

> If all these plans are carried out Winnipeg will speedily be a railway [*hub*](https://books.google.de/books?id=SC9CAQAAIAAJ&q=%22railway+hub%22&dq=%22railway+hub%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju96rKtoLhAhUFLFAKHc02AUw4FBDoATAEegQIARAT) in earnest, receiving not only the Canadian Pacific and the Northern Pacific, but an array of the wealthiest and most progressive railways upon the continent… — *Railway World* 32 (1888), 471.
>
> The Railway [*Hub*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22railway%20hub%22;id=mdp.39015015393088;view=1up;seq=874;start=1;sz=10;page=search;num=94) and Commercial Centre of the Dakotas, Aberdeen is now the leading business and Railway City of the two Dakotas… Advertisement, *Scribner’s*, 1889.

Comment: I doubt that. Wagons wheels had hubs and I bet people in pre-automobile days also used it. Hub and spoke is the origin.

Comment: @Lambie: This was from etymonline. You're welcome to find earlier examples that aren't just one-off metaphors. Medieval European cities discarded the Roman grid for marketplaces whose sidestreets went by the most direct route. You'd think that metaphor might have dawned on some random wheelwright.

Comment: Why you mentioning Roman grids?? Hubs are from wheels, that also have spokes. Paris has the Rond Point des Champs-Elysées, which has this structure, and also Washington, DC whose creator copied the French.

Comment: Physical hubs have been around for ages, but the issue is when people started using it metaphorically.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary lists its figurative use and has the same first quote from 1858. In this case, etymonline may have taken information from there.

Answer (score 0):

[Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hub):

> "solid center of a wheel," 1640s, of uncertain origin, perhaps, if all
>   the senses are in fact the same word, from hubbe, originally probably
>   "lump, round protuberance, boss," the source of the hob of a fireplace
>   and the hobnail of a boot. A wheelwright's word, not generally known
>   or used until c. 1828; it reached wider currency with the vogue for
>   bicycling. **Meaning "center of interest or activity or importance"
>   first recorded 1858 in writings of Oliver W. Holmes, and originally
>   especially of Boston.**
>
> Boston State-House is the hub of the solar system. [Holmes, "Autocrat of the Breakfast Table"]
>
> [E]verybody knows that Boston used to be called the Hub, meaning the hub of the universe. It may still be the hub, because the center of a wheel moves slowly. [J.P. Marquand, "Life," March 24, 1941]

Comment: Yes, all roads lead the Boston. The in-leading roads are the bloody spokes. Ha ha.

Comment: @Lambie -- Oddly, when I tried to get to Boston (umpty-ump years ago) I couldn't find the right turnoff.  Went around in that bloody circle about five times before I figured it out.

Comment: Well, there's no ring road in Boston. It's all very nook-shoten (A word my Dad taught me which I am using incorrectly. But it's colorful.) The only circle might be going along the Charles, crossing to Cambridge and back again into town? [OH, I see, Route 128 aka Route 95 . It goes round in a HUGE circle. Right. )

Comment: @Lambie - I don't recall the numbers, but 128/95 sounds about right.  It was a sort of oblong loop, coming up from the south, and myself and several friends experienced difficulties finding the right turn, as it did a tight loop near the river.  There was a bridge off to the right that looked about right, but just as you were about to make the turn onto it you saw a "DO NO ENTER" sign and had to abort.